# How do I install Windows XP from Ubuntu Live Pen Drive?

Tags: live-usb, windows-xp

I've tried to install Windows XP in my mom's netbook, the problem is best described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/481307/how-to-make-an-usb-bootable-with-windows-xp).

In the comments someone says that I can format the HDD with a pendrive of Ubuntu, and then reformat the HDD with another pendrive with Windwos XP, the thing is: I don't want to format the HDD unless it works, is there any way to install Windows XP from a pendrive Ubuntu Live??

Comment: Questions about installing Windows are off-topic for Ask Ubuntu. Please ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: @ScottSeverance I asked there, and then someone suggest to do what I'm asking... Well something like that...

Comment: You have to install Windows from an appropriate Windows installation medium. Ubuntu live flash drives are for Ubuntu. You can, of course, do maintenance tasks, but you can't install Windows.

Comment: @ScottSeverance but there is something that I can do with a pendrive of ubuntu in order to make an installation of windows XP, it doesn't matter if I have to reformat, just something that does work...

Comment: Additional note after reading your question on Super User: I'm not familiar with the technique recommended by the other user, but it seems to me like what he's recommending would be more along the lines of a disk image. Have you checked out the site recommended? It might turn out that I'm wrong. But I'm fairly confident of my answer.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Which site recommended??

Comment: Pen Drive Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't possible, as far as I know. The suggestion you received on Super User to check out [Pen Drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) is bad advice because according to the website that tool is only for installing Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Well, I think he says something like format HDD with an Ubuntu Live and then install windows with other USB, but I almost was sure it is impossible... thanks!!

Comment: Sure. You can reformat the disk with the live USB (though I'm not sure about formatting it as NTFS), but what use is that if you can't install Windows afterward?

Comment: @ScootSeverance That's what I tought, but he seems to be pretty sure of what I'm asking here...